# ElFinder multiple roots with MySQL drive

Tags: mysql, elfinder

I'm not sure if it's possible to have a connector with multiple MySQL roots. When I try with just one root it works perfect. My code with 2 roots look like this:

```
[
    'locale' => 'es_ES.UTF-8',
    'bind' => false,
    'debug' => true,
    'roots' => [
        (int) 0 => [
            (int) 0 => [
                'driver' => 'MySQL',
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'user' => 'user',
                'pass' => 'pass',
                'db' => 'elfinder_db',
                'files_table' => 'files',
                'path' => '1'
            ],
            (int) 1 => [
                'driver' => 'MySQL',
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'user' => 'user',
                'pass' => 'pass',
                'db' => 'elfinder_db',
                'files_table' => 'files',
                'path' => '6'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try simple array.

```
[
    'locale' => 'es_ES.UTF-8',
    'bind' => false,
    'debug' => true,
    'roots' => [
        [
            'driver' => 'MySQL',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'user' => 'user',
            'pass' => 'pass',
            'db' => 'elfinder_db',
            'files_table' => 'files',
            'path' => '1'
        ],
        [
            'driver' => 'MySQL',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'user' => 'user',
            'pass' => 'pass',
            'db' => 'elfinder_db',
            'files_table' => 'files',
            'path' => '6'
        ]
    ]
]
```